# Migrating spring-data-redis from 2.6.2 to 3.1. Unable to add/connect Message Listener

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

During migration Spring Boot from version 2.6.2 to 3.1, I was switching also **spring-data-redis** from 2.6.2 to 3.1 and have encountered problem that Message Listener bean can not be started anymore. Exception itself does not describe too much as it only says that:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'jedisMessageListenerContainer'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext"}
```

Where `jedisMessageListenerContainer` looks as following:

```java
    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer jedisMessageListenerContainer(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory,
                                                                RedisKeyExpirationListener redisListener) {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(redisListener, new PatternTopic(
                "__keyevent@0__:expired"));
        container.setErrorHandler(e -> log.error("There was an error in redis key expiration listener container", e));
        return container;
    }
```

`RedisKeyExpirationListener` is a class that implements `MessageListener` interface from the **spring-data-redis**

After some debugging I have find out only that `RedisMessageListenerContainer` is catching `TimeoutException` and then throwing

```
IllegalStateException("Subscription registration timeout exceeded", e);
```

Which is later being caught by Bean Processor and parsed into `Failed to start bean` exception message.

I have tried to increase the `MaxSubscriptionRegistrationWaitingTime` for the container (up to 60 seconds) but it just resulted in longer waiting time for same exception.

---

I am using the Message Listener together with Jedis (version 4.4.2 but also checked with [4.3.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis/3.1.0) which should be compatible) as the connection factory and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` with version **3.1.0**.
Here is implementation of the connection factory:

```java
    @Bean
    public JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
        var jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(10);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(0);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(8);
        return jedisPoolConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig) {

        var jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder()
                .usePooling()
                .poolConfig(jedisPoolConfig)
                .and()
                .readTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000L))
                .useSsl()
                .build();
```

---

As additional test I have just removed the `addMessageListener` invocation on the Redis container and application was able to work with the Redis itself. The problem only starts to appear when I add the `Message Listener` to the `RedisMessageListenerContainer`.

Also when bringing back spring to version 2.6.2 together with spring-data-redis `Message Listener` works and I can see that expired events are being handled.

Can someone help why this happening and why I cannot initialize the beans once want to add this listener?

I tried to:

1. Update the Jedis, Spring Boot, spring-data-redis and spring-boot-starter-data-redis dependencies to the newest as also to one that are compatible with Spring Boot version 3
2. Increase the connection pool and timeouts.
3. Remove the listener to check if application starts to work (It worked without listener)
4. Change the implementation according to the spring-data-redis [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:pubsub:subscribe:adapter) to the following one:

```java
    @Bean
    RedisKeyExpirationListener redisListener() {
        return new RedisKeyExpirationListener();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter redisListenerAdapter(RedisKeyExpirationListener redisListener) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(redisListener, "handleMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer jedisMessageListenerContainer(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory,
                                                                MessageListenerAdapter redisListenerAdapter) {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(redisListenerAdapter, new PatternTopic(
                "__keyevent@0__:expired"));
        container.setErrorHandler(e -> log.error("There was an error in redis key expiration listener container", e));
        return container;
    }
```

where now `RedisKeyExpirationListener` does implement own interface:

```
public interface MessageDelegate {

    void handleMessage(String message);

    void handleMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern);
}
```

instead implementing `MessageListener` interface from the **spring-data-redis**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expierencing `Failed to start bean exception message`during local testing of Redis functionalities, try to comment **.useSSl()** in jedisConnectionFactory class.